# java 8 stream : Use map to change last element in a List

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following code:

```
List<String> list= Arrays.asList("a","b","c");
list.stream()
    .map(x->{
        //if(isLast()) return "last";
        return x;
    })
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

I want to change the last item in the list with "last" so the program will return something like this

```
a
b
last
```

**NOTE**: I know I can do this very easy without streams, but I'm interested if this can be achieved with streams.

**NOTE2**: I provided a simple example, so I can easily understand the stream concept

Comment: Just do it with a loop, it will be much simpler. Java streams don't naturally support operations such as `zip` or `zipWithIndex`.

Comment: A stream does not necessarily provide the elements in the same order as they are in the underlying list. Additionally, what exactly are you actually hunting for? Do you want to change the list or do you simply want to print the list with reacting to the last element?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose You said that a stream does not necessarily provide the elements in the right order, but the `Collection.stream` documentation says that it returns a sequential stream. The only way this stream could be out of order is if the `List` implementation being used overrode the `stream` or `spliterator` methods.

Comment: @Sam nope, you can also call `Stream.unordered` to tell the stream that the order can be broken if needed. But again, it's only when you are the consumer of the stream that this can be a problem. If you are the producer, you are well aware of its order

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about this:

```
<T> Stream<T> replaceLast(List<T> items, T last) {
    Stream<T> allExceptLast = items.stream().limit(items.size() - 1);
    return Stream.concat(allExceptLast, Stream.of(last));
}
```

The method makes two separate streams, one containing all except the last item of the input list, and a second containing only the replacement final item. Then it returns the concatenation of those two streams.

Example invocation:

```
>>> List<String> items = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");
>>> replaceLast(items, "last").forEach(System.out::println);
one
two
last
```

Thinking about it, if using `Stream.limit` is uncomfortable, `Stream<T> allExceptLast = items.subList(0, items.size() - 1).stream();` is also possible.

Comment: Although it works and is not a horrible hack as the other answer, I think people on Stack Overflow should not try to answer any question. Sometimes our role is to say *Dude, what you're trying to do does not make sense, do it this other way which is better*. To me this is absolutely not the kind of things a stream is good for, just look how much shorter it would be with a loop

Comment: @Dici but there are cases where having access to a `Stream` is incredibly useful, or even obligatory. It all depends on the use case. The OP already said that they are specifically looking for a stream-based solution and that this is a simplified version of the real scenario.

Comment: For me the advantage of a method like this over using a loop is that it makes the filtering step reusable. Now you have access, any time you want, to an iterator that replaces the last item of a list. What's not to like?

Comment: Fair enough. In a broader context it might make sense. +1

Comment: Conceptionally, both ways are identical, but given the current implementation, `items.subList(0, items.size() - 1).stream()` is more efficient than `items.stream().limit(items.size() - 1)`.

Answer (score 7):

I don't expect this answer to be upvoted because I won't directly answer your question, but I think there must be someone to clearly say this.

Stack Overflow is not a place where we should try giving answers to any question. Sometimes the best thing to do is to explain the OP that his approach is wrong and show him a better approach.

In this particular case, I think streams are not what you are looking for. You should see streams as sequences and the way you process it is usually element by element, there is most of the time no lookback or look forward. A stream could possibly be infinite or really huge, and you don't know when it will finish.

On the contrary, a list is a finite data structure with a given size. The notion of *last* element is well defined. The only reason other people have been able to give you an answer is that they are using the fact they know the stream is coming from a list. With a general stream that could come from anywhere, you would not be able to do that.

The stream approach to such problem would be to use an iterator, which is completely agnostic to the origin of the stream.

```
Stream<String> stream = someStream;
Iterator<String> it = stream.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
     String next = it.next();
     System.out.println(it.hasNext() ? "last" : next);
}
```

This is not pretty, but this is the right streamy approach. Now, you have a list so you can also do the traditional `for` loop. However, this iterator loop is actually the best way to do it with a unknown list. The `for` loop will only work well for random access lists and will be slow with the others.

Comment: Using the `hasNext()` check to identify the last item is a neat approach and makes for a very elegant loop. Great solution for when you have a stream (or indeed any iterable) as input and want an iterator that does this.

Comment: Thanks for your post. I upvoted your answer. I understand the streams concept, but I wanted an answer for this particular case when I'm using a finite data structure . The reason I'm using streams is because is much more easy to apply filters and other cool stuff.

Comment: @DouaBeri Sam's solution is clean and he proposed a good argument for why it can be useful to do it this way. If you handle the stream to someone else, his answer will be better. If the stream comes from someone else, mine will be better. It's actually interesting because it depends on the point of view (producer or consumer). Thanks for the upvote ^^

Answer (score 3):

> I want to change the last item in the list with "last"

You don't need (or want) to use a stream. Just [`set()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-) the last element directly:

```
list.set(list.size() - 1, "last");
```

If for some reason (not stated) you absolutely must use a stream, then you have a problem because streams don't know where their current positions is relative to the rest of the stream.

You can introduce a counter into the lambda by circumventing the "effectively final" requirement of referenced variables like this:

```
int[] index = {0}; // array is effectively final (contents may change!)
list.stream()
    .map(x -> ++index[0] == list.size() ? "last" : x)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Don't do this unless you're sure the lambda won't be used elsewhere, because while lists stream their elements sequentially, other streams may stream in parallel, in which case your special action will happen at an indeterminate position in the stream.

Comment: I know about this. I want to do this with stream. I provided a simple example so i can understand the concept more easy.

Comment: Well, it now depends on what OP really wants: change the last element only for printing (his version) or mutate the source list. Maybe he can tell us.

Comment: He did not say he wanted to set the last element to `"last"` but to print it as `"last"`, at least in my understanding

Comment: @DouaBeri OK. I have posted a stream-based solution

Comment: The second snippet is a horrible hack. This should NEVER be done in real code

Comment: Well .. additionally, a stream could potentially provide the elements in another order than the original list had. The last list element might not be the last stream element!

Comment: @Dici why not do it? Why is it a "horrible" hack? It works for non-parallel streams, which `List#stream()` returns.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose `List#stream()` returns a non-parallel stream

Comment: @Bohemian this is against functional programming paradigm, this is unelegant and has no advantage over a loop. As you mentionned, it also does not work with parallel streams but the **whole point** of streams and functional programming is that everything should be immutable so that functions are **pure** and it does not matter which thread runs their code.

Comment: Yes, I know. But as OP is obviously a beginner, a word of warning should accompany your "solution". It cannot (or better should not) be carried over to other code areas .. . well, at least not to all other areas. Additionally, as your "solution" is not free of side-effects.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose fair comment. I've added a "do not try this at home" disclaimer

Comment: This is against the idea of a stream. Abstractly, streams do not know when they will be terminated (or in your case when the list will be over). +1 for this answer.

Comment: @ReutSharabani wait, I agreed with your comment until the +1. What is your rational for upvoting this answer which goes against your first sentence ? He's providing a completely anti-pattern solution. I would be sad if this answer made it to the top. The other one using `Stream.concat` is much much cleaner

Comment: @Dici he is giving an answer but making sure to note the correct way first: "You don't need (or want) to use a stream. Just set() the last element directly..."

Comment: @ReutSharabani this part is wrong because it mutates the list, which is not what the OP wants. He only wants to print the last element differently, not change the state of the list

Comment: This detail has nothing to do with the streaming abstraction. It should be absent from his code. Copy the list and replace the last element if necessary.